# Navigation bar and Toolbar in ipad app at top of screen - apple's approval?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uinavigationbar, uitoolbar, ui-guidelines

I have got a wire frame for ipad application, in which navigation bar and tool bars are placed on the top. And back button is placed in toolbar. Whether it violates apple's guidelines or will it be approved by apple for itunes store. Also one screen have toolbar like a navigation bar. Will it be a problem in approval? [image]

[image]

Comment: No, I don't think this will be a problem. You think they would be very strict, but I've experienced they could be quite lenient.

Comment: Thanks. But someone said that there should not be tool bar look like a  navigation bar. So thought of asking this.

Comment: no, There is not any issue in this.

Comment: Of course, just because it would't get rejected doesn't mean you should use such a design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll be fine. As long as your UI makes sense and does what it's supposed to, then I wouldn't worry.

If you haven't already, you should read Apple's Human Interface Guidelines. It will tell you all the do's and don'ts of designing a UI. And remember, they are what they are. Guidelines, not rules. I've never heard of an app being rejected because it didn't conform to them.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I read the guidelines. But I was having some doubt. So thought of asking this question.